# AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS EC2, When i run this command

```
dmidecode --type 17

Handle 0x1107, DMI type 17, 21 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x1000
        Error Information Handle: 0x0000
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 10312 MB
        Form Factor: DIMM
        Set: None
        Locator: DIMM 7
        Bank Locator: Not Specified
        Type: RAM
        Type Detail: None
```

Its not showing me the , the RAM Speed information . My Server RAM IS 122 GB but using a very low . I want to find the RAM Speed , Read/Write speed .

If you know any good tools please let me share .

Comment: Question not exactly clear, but seems RAM speed related

Answer (score -1):

I create a ramps disk on RAM .

```
# mkdir -p /mnt/ram
# mount -t ramfs -o size=20m ramfs /mnt/ram
```

Then use mount command to see disk status.

```
# mount
/dev/sda2 on / type ext3 (rw)
proc on /proc type proc (rw)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,gid=5,mode=620)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext3 (rw)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw)
none on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw)
sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
tmpfs on /mnt/tmp type tmpfs (rw,size=20m)
ramfs on /mnt/ram type ramfs (rw,size=20m)
```

Check ram inforamation by free command then fun the command

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/ram/file3 bs=10G count=1 oflag=dsync
```

Check again , i am sharing my terminal image , hope it will clear you .

[image]

Comment: Answer refers to RAM usage, not to RAM Speed, which most likely seems to be the expected answer, although the requester is not 100% clear on the question